# How can i see that bumblebee has disabled nvidia?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Im trying to find out how to see if bumblebee which i installed on my 12.10 installation on my k55vd asus laptop...

How can know for sure that bumblebee is turning the nvidia off?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for (run at a command line):

```
$ optirun --status
```

If the discrete card is disabled, it will show `X inactive. Discrete video card is off.`. If it's enabled, it will show something like `X is PID 24432, 1 applications using bumblebeed.`.

Or, if you're using KDE, you can add the widget "Bumblebee Indicatior" (sic) [1]. It shows an icon that's either black or yellow depending on the video card status.

[1] http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Bumblebee+Indicatior?content=154575